# Compare dates in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing code that compares two dates from a userform and a columm from an array.

If it's between those, then set the entire row in another array.

```
Dim vD1 As Variant                                         
Dim vD2 As Variant
vD1 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
vD2 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

If vD1 = Empty Then
  vD1 = #1/1/2010#
End If

If vD2 = Empty Then
  vD2 = #1/1/2100#
End If

vD1 = Format(vD1, "General Number")
vD2 = Format(vD2, "General Number")

For i = 1 To 100
  If myArray5(i, 1) >= vD1 Then
    If myArray5(i, 1) <= vD2 Then
      For j = 1 To 8
        myArray6(i, j) = myArray5(i, j)
      Next j
    End If
  End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 100
  If myArray5(i, 1) <= vD1 Then
    If myArray5(i, 1) >= vD2 Then
      For j = 1 To 8
        myArray6(i, j) = Empty
      Next j
    End If
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? What is myArray5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Really this depends on what is in myArray5 and myArray6, and how those are formatted. For more information on date comparison methods and functions in Excel VBA, check [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805573199990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&CTT=5&origin=HV080557283) from the Excel Developer site.

Also, from a bird's eye view, you could improve by combining **If...Then** statements with an **And** statement, for example:

```
If (myArray5(i, 1) >= vD1) and (myArray5(i, 1) <= vD2) Then _
myArray6(i, j) = myArray5(i, j)
```

Also you might try adding comments and indentation to your code - this will greatly help debugging!